# flutter radio button to different page

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

I want to make a payment page. First, users have to pick the payment method using radio button and it has 5 options, then when users choose the payment method and click the 'pay' button it shows a page that the payment was done successfully. But I want when the users choose option number 5, and click the 'pay' button, the payment will be failed (redirect to failed page and back to the payment page again to choose another option) how can I make it? Make the pay button redirect to a different page when the users pick the number 5 option?

This is the code for the radio button and the pay button :

```
  Expanded(
    child: ListView.separated(
      itemCount: paymentLabels.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Radio<int?>(
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            value: index,
            groupValue: value,
            onChanged: (i) => setState(() => value = i),
          ),
          title: Text(
            paymentLabels[index],
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          trailing: Icon(paymentIcons[index], color: Colors.black),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Divider();
      },
    ),
  ),
  DefaultButton(
      btnText: 'PAY',
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Success(),
          )))
],
  ),
);
```

and this is for the additional code for radio button:

```
  final paymentLabels = [
  'Credit card / Debit card',
  'Go-Pay',
  'OVO',
  'ShopeePay',
];

final paymentIcons = [
  Icons.credit_card,
  Icons.money_outlined,
  Icons.payment,
  Icons.account_balance_wallet,
];
```

please help, thank you

Comment: Where is your 5th radio button ?

Comment: I haven't added it yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by index number.

Comment: can it check one by one? how does it work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).